# How to yield from __next__ method?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iterator, generator, yield

I thought the following code would express the desired result:

```
class LockIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, lock_list):
        self.lock_list = lock_list

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):

        for resource in self.lock_list:
            print( "Locking N resources" )

            yield resource
            print( "Unlocking N resources" )

        print( "Unlocking remaining resources" )
        raise StopIteration


for item in LockIterator( ["Resource 1", "Resource 2", "Resource 3"] ):
    print("Safe resource usage:", item)
```

But, running it on Python I got an infinity loop:

```
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BDA24938>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BB8AEE60>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BDA24938>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BB8AEE60>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BDA24938>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BB8AEE60>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BDA24938>
Safe resource usage: <generator object LockIterator.__next__ at 0x000001A8BB8AEE60>
...
```

In my imagination, it was supposed to run like this:

```
Locking N resources
Safe resource usage: Resource 1
Unlocking N resources
Locking N resources
Safe resource usage: Resource 2
Unlocking N resources
Locking N resources
Safe resource usage: Resource 3
Unlocking N resources
Unlocking remaining resources
```

Do you know how could automatically force this behavior in a ordinary for loop?

```
for item in LockIterator( ["Resource 1", "Resource 2", "Resource 3"] ):
    print("Safe resource usage:", item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__next__` is called every time the for loop needs a new item. Since your `__next__` is a generator, that is what is returned every time.

Instead, you could get rid of the class and just write a generator:

```
def LockIterator(lock_list):
    # better name this lockify or something else in snake_case
    for resource in lock_list:
        print("Locking N resources")

        yield resource
        print("Unlocking N resources")

    print("Unlocking remaining resources")
```

Answer (score 3):

I also manage to fix it by deleting the `__next__` and moving its body to the `__iter__` method:

```
class LockIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, lock_list):
        self.lock_list = lock_list

    def __iter__(self):

        for resource in self.lock_list:
            print( "Locking N resources" )

            yield resource
            print( "Unlocking N resources" )

        print( "Unlocking remaining resources" )

for item in LockIterator( ["Resource 1", "Resource 2", "Resource 3"] ):
    print("Safe resource usage:", item)
```